# How do I check my limits on publish_stream?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Let's say a user selects 50 facebook ids that are his friends.

I take each facebook id and post a message on each person's wall. (Making 50 publish_stream api calls)

What is the limit for Facebook? How do I check how many I can post on behalf of the user?

Comment: i think its 25 for posting on friends wall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no longer a limit on doing this. But in my company we stopped practicing publish_stream at all after Facebook banned 3 applications using this and we had to make long conversations with them. It's written nowhere on what basis but there is definetly an algorithm catching applications that publish a lot.

When we did that I found many comments on different limits. It seems that it all depends on the application history. This means, if your applicatin is new and generates many streams in the first day it will be caught as spamy. If the app has long history and large user base you can afford that.

Comment: Could this be it?  Feature, Requests 1.0  ... limit per user, 50 (under "diagnostics")